# Remote Desktop ActiveX control

Tags: c#, activex, remote-desktop

I've got a C# application that I've been using for years to script remote desktop connections.  It's always been built on the AxMsRdpClient3 (note the 3, which I guess is some kind of version number).  There are features in AxMsRdpClient8 (version 8) that I want to be able to use, but as I understand it, this requires Remote Desktop version 8 to be installed.  Not all users have that installed (or even can install it on Windows XP/Vista), though.

So as Sheng Jiang suggested, I am creating the control at runtime now and I have code that looks like this:

```
try
{
    AxMsRdpClient8 rdp8 = new AxMsRdpClient8();
    rdp8.BeginInit();
    //  set some properties here
    rdp8.EndInit(); // throws Exception on machines without version 8 installed
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    AxMsRdpClient3 rdp3 = new AxMsRdpClient3();
    rdp3.BeginInit();
    //  set some properties here
    rdp3.EndInit();
}
```

As expected, rdp8.EndInit() throws an exception on machines that do not have Remote Desktop version 8 installed.  The problem is that after we try to create the AxMSRDPClient8, the rdp3.EndInit() fails as well (class not registered) on older machines.  If I don't attempt to create the AxMSRDPClient8 first, the AxMSRDPClient3 initializes and works correctly.

Comment: add os detection code to avoiding trying in the first place.

Comment: I could detect the OS, but the OS doesn't really tell you which AxMsRdpClient version to use.  For example, Remote Desktop 8 is available for download for Windows 7, but it doesn't come installed by default.  Plus, if I detected the OS, my code wouldn't function on the next version of Windows where something like above would continue to work.  Is the concept above not valid for activeX controls?  Why would a valid activeX control fail just because you had an invalid one before?

Comment: Each of the CLSIDs is compatible with later system versions. For example, the CLSID for the scriptable control on Windows Vista will work on later system versions, such as Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[each version of RDP activeX has a different clsid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You need to detect the OS version and create [an activex at runtime with the class id corresponding to the lowest OS version you plan to support](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10822/Dynamically-adding-ActiveX-controls-in-managed-cod).

If your code depends on late binding, better rewrite your code to work with IMsRdpClient* and IMsRdpClientNonScriptable*. For example MsRdpClient8NotSafeForScripting supports the following interfaces:

- up to version 8 of IMsRdpClient*
- up to version 5 of IMsRdpClientNonScriptable
- IMsTscNonScriptable
- IMsRdpPreferredRedirectionInfo
- IMsRdpExtendedSettings

MsRdpClient3NotSafeForScripting supports

- version 2 of IMsRdpClient*
- IMsRdpClientNonScriptable
- IMsTscNonScriptable.

if you want to detect whether your activex support a particular interface version, just cast the ActiveX's instance 
to the interface. when a cast fails you know the interface is not supported.

```
protected void CreateRdpActiveX()
{
    try
    {
        string clsid=GetRdpActiveXClsIdByOSVersion();
        Type type = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(clsid, true);
        this.axRdp = new AxHost (type.GUID.ToString());
        ((ISupportInitialize)(axRdp)).BeginInit();
        SuspendLayout();
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(axRdp);     
        ((ISupportInitialize)(axRdp)).EndInit();
        ResumeLayout(false);
        var msRdpClient8 = axRdp.GetOcx() as IMsRdpClient8;
        if(msRdpClient8!=null)
        {
             var advancedSettings9 =msRdpClient8.AdvancedSettings9 as IMsRdpClientAdvancedSettings8;
             if(advancedSettings9!=null) 
                 advancedSettings9.BandwidthDetection=true;

        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of interface version detection?

Comment: I finally got around to trying this suggestion out.  The first problem is that Type.GetTypeFromCLSID take a GUID, not a String.  I assume I just pass it a new GUID(clsid) instead of clsid.  The problem I can't solve is that AxHost is an abstract class and can't be created on line 7.  You know the workaround for that?

Comment: I made a concrete subclass of AxHost and that seemed to get me past not being able to create the AxHost and now I can compile my class and run through it without error.  My new problem is that I had some event handlers on the AxMsRdpClient objects.  How can I attach these event handlers (OnConnected, etc) to the object now that it is an AxHost instead of an AxMsRdpClient object?

Comment: To add my events back, I ended up finding some random code on the internet that did the trick.  I totally don't understand what it's doing, but I created a class that implements the IMsTscAxEvents interface, and then called override CreakSink() in my AxHost subclass and called: System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.ConnectionPointCookie(GetOcx(), this.eventMulticaster, typeof(MSTSCLib.IMsTscAxEvents));

Comment: Yes, events are implemented as IConnectionPointContainer so you need a  sink and a cookie to hook up events. The aximp tool creates wrapper classes that creates one sink per delegates which is much less efficient.

Comment: @Jason can you please share how did you create AxHost object and get the event details